# How to communicate from `Outlet` to pages

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My Layout.tsx:

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Layout: FC = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Mohamed');
  const updateName = (value) => {
    setName(value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <header>Header</header>
      <main>
        <Outlet props={name} fun={updateName} />
      </main>
      <footer>footer</footer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

my register page:

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';

export const Register: FC = ({
  name,
  fun,
}: {
  name: string;
  fun: (string) => void;
}) => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState<string>();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(name); //undefined
    setOption(name);
  }, [name]);

  const updateName = () => {
    fun('new name');
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{option}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => updateName()}>Click Me </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In my register page, name consoling as `undefined` when I try to update the name from  `updateName` by calling `inc` getting an error. any one show me the right way please?

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-urbsn3?file=register/Register.tsx)

index.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Register } from './register/Register';
import { Layout } from './layout/Layout';
import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
          <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: To communicate between two components, the two major ways are through props, and through Context, you can either pass from layout a callback to update its members to its children, or you could wrap them all in a context that you can update from any of its children

Comment: yes, agree. need as answer by updating the code. can you help me espeically `pass from layout a callback` approch?

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer:

Layout.tsx:

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Layout: FC = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Mohamed');
  const updateName = (value) => {
    setName('new name');
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <header>Header</header>
      <main>
        <Outlet context={[name, updateName]} />
      </main>
      <footer>footer</footer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Register.tsx:

```
import { FC, useState } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Register: FC = () => {
  const [name, updateName] = useOutletContext();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Register page {name}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => updateName()}>Click Me </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

now the data can be shard from outlet to page, and page can update the outlet props as well calling the function